# Android (Xamarin) specific wear layout

Tags: android, android-layout, layout, xamarin, wear-os

I need a layout, which uses on android wear in settings menu.
Its look like left side its an image, right side its a text. When you are scrolling up or down there are 3 items on screen. On the middle of the screen image and text are bigger then upper text and image or lower.
[image]

**UPDATE**

In this [link](https://developer.android.com/training/wearables/ui/lists.html#adapter) example on step "Create an Adapter to Populate the List" in method `onCreateViewHolder` i cant inflate a layout  `mInflater.inflate(R.layout.list_item, null)` while app starts i have got an exception:

> Binary XML file line #1: Error inflating class
>   com.companyname.testcircleviewlayout.WearableListItemLayout

Here is layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<com.companyname.testcircleviewlayout.WearableListItemLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:gravity="center_vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="80dp">
    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/circle"
        android:layout_height="20dp"
        android:layout_margin="16dp"
        android:layout_width="20dp"
        android:src="@drawable/wl_circle"/>
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/name"
        android:gravity="center_vertical|left"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:lineSpacingExtra="-4sp"
        android:textColor="@android:color/darker_gray"
        android:textSize="16sp"/>
</com.companyname.testcircleviewlayout.WearableListItemLayout>
```

Can anybody help?

**UPDATE 2**

Need add to androidManifest next lines:

```
<activity>
           <strong>
            android:name=".CustomWearableList"
            android:label="WearableList" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter></strong>
        </activity>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Layout is a simple one, an image on the left, a TextView on the right. You can use the WearableListView to do most of the work; it extends RecyclerView and there are callbacks there to inform you when a row is moved to the center or moved off of the center. In the example you have above, I don't think the size of text is any different between rows; the off-center ones are faded somewhat. You need to use a simple animator that enlarges an image and one that reduces the size and using the abovementioned callbacks, when an item is moved to the center, animate and enlarge the image by a small factor and when it goes off-center, animate it to the original size. [This training](https://developer.android.com/training/wearables/ui/lists.html) is a good starting point.

Comment: I do not have anything on Xamarin, I do not use that at all, sorry.